# Maven plugin classloader not finding a file that should be in the classpath

Tags: maven, plugins, build, classloader, maven-plugin

I created a new Maven plugin to generate some source files for a project I am working on. Each file naturally needs the company's copyright information at the top of each file. Trying to do things the best I can, I wanted to put the copyright information in a separate text file rather than hard-code in the source.

In my plugin, I am trying to get this file using the `getResourceAsStream()` method provided by the class loader:

```
    InputStream inputStream = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
        "/com/company/java-header.txt"
    );
```

When I test the plugin in isolation, this code works. The `java-header.txt` is properly placed in Maven's target directory in the correct location, and the tests pass.

Now for the next step, I want to utilize this plugin in another Maven module. If I don't include the copyright header for each java file, the plugin works as expected. So I know it's not another problem with how I wrote the Maven plugin.

When I run the plugin with the above code, I get the following exception:

```
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.company.AbstractJavaSchemaFile.generate(AbstractJavaSchemaFile.java:12)
        at com.company.AbstractJavaSchemaFile.generateAndWriteToFile(AbstractJavaSchemaFile.java:8)
        at com.company.SchemaGenerator.generateSchemaBaseClass(SchemaGenerator.java:41)
        at com.company.SchemaGenerator.generateSchemaFiles(SchemaGenerator.java:36)
        at com.company.SchemaGenerator.execute(SchemaGenerator.java:28)
        at com.company.SchemaGenerator.execute(SchemaGenerator.java:20)
        at com.company.SchemaGeneratorMojo.execute(SchemaGeneratorMojo.java:37)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: com.company.SchemaGeneratorException: Cannot find [com/company/java-header.txt] in your classpath.
        at com.company.JavaSchemaFileBuilder.verifyJavaHeaderIsFoundInClassPath(JavaSchemaFileBuilder.java:47)
        at com.company.JavaSchemaFileBuilder.readJavaHeader(JavaSchemaFileBuilder.java:31)
        at com.company.JavaSchemaFileBuilder.<clinit>(JavaSchemaFileBuilder.java:15)
```

The error `com.company.SchemaGeneratorException: Cannot find [com/company/java-header.txt] in your classpath` is a custom error message. It throws this exception when the `InputStream` returned by the classloader is `null`.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get Maven plugin to read this `java-header.txt` file from the classpath? As far as I know, it is using the target compiled files in the plugin's directory to run the plugin. The java-header.txt file is there. Here is the url information Maven also prints out:

```
**urls[0] = file:/C:/Path/to/my/project/my-maven-plugin/target/classes/**
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.6/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.3.0/sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.2/commons-io-1.2.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.3/dom4j-1.3.jar
```

Comment: Can you show us the pom where you are _using_ the maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

someClass.getResource() will return path as mvn:artifactID/groupID/version. While r files in regular JVM returns file protocol. OSGi based jvm will return maven path.